# Geometry has too many edges (Google Earth Engine). Help me

Tags: google-earth-engine

[image]

I have problem during working in Google Earth Engine. I was processing some vector files. And i am getting below code:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The geometry has too many vertices. You can try to simplify it using:

```js
// Get a feature collection and subset the first feature.
var feature = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/States").first();

// Simplify the feature - think of max error as resolution.
// Setting to 100 means that the geometry is accurate to
// within 100 meters, for example.
var featureSimple = ee.Feature(feature).simplify({maxError: 100});
```

or for a `ee.FeatureCollection`:

```js
// Get a feature collection.
var featureCol = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2018/States");

// Simplify each feature in the collection, by mapping the
// .simplify() function over it. 
var simplifiedCol = featureCol.map(function(feature) {
  return feature.simplify({maxError: 100});
});
```